# WebClient exception handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-webclient

I want to make exception handler for my WebClient, which calls external API. I don't want to use onStatus() method, due to I have abstract web client with different methods where I have to process exceptions, so I have to copy paste each onStatus() in my every abstract method. I want to make something similar to the rest template approach: we can implement ResponseErrorHandler and add our implementation into resttemplate e.g. setExceptionHandler(ourImplementation). I want the one class to handle all the exceptions.
Thanks for your advice in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Bean
  public WebClient buildWebClient() {

    Function<ClientResponse, Mono<ClientResponse>> webclientResponseProcessor =
        clientResponse -> {
          HttpStatus responseStatus = clientResponse.statusCode();
          if (responseStatus.is4xxClientError()) {
            System.out.println("4xx error");
            return Mono.error(new MyCustomClientException());
          } else if (responseStatus.is5xxServerError()) {
            System.out.println("5xx error");
            return Mono.error(new MyCustomClientException());
          }
          return Mono.just(clientResponse);
        };

    return WebClient.builder()
    .filter(ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(webclientResponseProcessor)).build();

}
```

We can use ResponseProcessor to write logic and handle different http statuses. This solution was tested and it works.

[GithubSample](https://gist.github.com/abhi2495/4607f2c827b2130ab6e08320f4ca5079)

Answer (score 0):

You can do smth like that

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorControllerAdvice {
  @ExceptionHandler({RuntimeException.class})
  public ResponseEntity<?> handleRuntimeException(RuntimeException e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
  }

  @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
  public ResponseEntity<?> handleRuntimeException(Exception e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
        .body(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I found more appropriate answer for me. If you are interesting in it, tap the link on my post!